# Can't configure linux routing, can't ping outside resources

Tags: linux, iproute

I've setup a Linux CentOS 7 virtual machine inside VirtualBox with 'host-only network interface'. Thus I now have a Linux guest with one eth interface and a Windows 10 host with three interfaces: ethernet with access to Internet, TAP-VPN Connection and VirtualBox Interface.

I can ping my linux guest from the host machine but not the other-way. I cannot setup 'network bridge' in the guest OS because I need it to have itsown network, so I can route everything from it into the VPN.

I tried to setup routing table myself, but totally failed. At the moment I can only ping 192.168.137.200 which is the guest's enp0s3 address and I neither can ping nor setup a route to 192.168.137.102 which is the address of the virtualbox network in the host OS.

Here is a state of my routing table (It's not the same as it was setup initially, I've messed it up while trying):

```
[root@localhost ~]# ip route
default via 192.168.137.102 dev enp0s3
192.168.137.0/24 dev enp0s3 proto static scope link
192.168.137.0/24 dev enp0s3 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.137.200 metric 100
192.168.137.102 dev enp0s3 proto static scope link
```

Then a few things I've tried:

```
[root@localhost ~]# ip route del default via 192.168.137.102 dev enp0s3
[root@localhost ~]# ip route add default via 192.168.137.102 scope link dev enp0s3
RTNETLINK answers: Network is unreachable
[root@localhost ~]# ip route add default via 192.168.137.102 dev enp0s3
[root@localhost ~]# ping 192.168.137.102
PING 192.168.137.102 (192.168.137.102) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 192.168.137.102 ping statistics ---
10 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 9001ms
```

I either get 'network is unreachable' error, or the route I add just does not work.

Comment: My 2 cents: most of the time the issue comes from the host not the guest. You can ping one way but not the other way: firewall. try `ip neigh` If you see the host (as something else than INCOMPLETE or FAILED) , that means ARP works (it has to for ping to work from host to guest and then reply to come back) => problem from host, not guest. Windows host problem? off-topic here

Answer (score 0):

As @A.B. pointed out in the comment, the reason was a Windows firewall. I've managed to allow ping (ICMP packets) by enabling a corresponding rule in it: it should be called in English something like 'echo - incoming ICMPv4'.